# Positive Lookbehind and Lookahead to the end of string

Tags: r, regex

My string patterns looks like this:
`UNB+UNOC:3+4399945681577+_GLN_Company__+180101:0050+10870` and I am trying to extract everything after the second last `+`, i.e. `180101:0050+10870`.

Thus far, I managed to address the second last block `180101:0050` with this expression `(?<=\+)[^\+]+(?=\+[^\+]*$)` but fail to include the last block including the last +. Here is my sample: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fTcdSO/1)

The expression is meant for R and I still need to escape the characters later on. This format it just for testing purposes in Regex101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could capture group based on the occurrence of `+` from the end (`$`) of the string.

```
sub(".*\\+([^+]+\\+[^+]+$)", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "180101:0050+10870"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "UNB+UNOC:3+4399945681577+_GLN_Company__+180101:0050+10870"
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun this works fine, too. Do you think that this can be changed to the tidyverse::str_replace() syntax, too. I am currently using all expressions in this functions and would try to maintain this for the sake of conciseness in my script.

Comment: @Max That would be just a direct translation `str_replace(str1,  ".*\\+([^+]+\\+[^+]+$)", "\\1")`

Comment: apologies, I accidentally missed the `"\\1"` at the end when adding it to the script. Perfect, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\+\K[^+]+\+[^+]*$
```

Or, if you would like to use it with `stringr::str_extract`:

```
(?<=\+)[^+]+\+[^+]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/im793n/1). Details:

- `\+` - a `+` char
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `(?<=\+)` - location right after a `+` symbol
- `[^+]+` - one or more chars other than `+`
- `\+` - a `+`
- `[^+]+` - one or more chars other than `+`
- `$` - end of string.

See [R demo online](https://ideone.com/IJSKeh):

```
x <- "UNB+UNOC:3+4399945681577+_GLN_Company__+180101:0050+10870"
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\+\\K[^+]+\\+[^+]*$", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "180101:0050+10870"
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\+)[^+]+\\+[^+]*$")
## => [1] "180101:0050+10870"
```

Comment: thanks and this works fine. Since this is the only expression I am missing in a row of extracts, do you think you could assist in adapting it to the tidyverse::str_extract() syntax, too ? It appears that the \K comment is not supported but this might be my misunderstanding as well. https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf

Comment: @Max Just use `str_extract(x, "(?<=\\+)[^+]+\\+[^+]*$")`, see [R demo](https://ideone.com/IJSKeh).

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do in this case:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("UNB+UNOC:3+4399945681577+_GLN_Company__+180101:0050+10870", "\\d+:\\d+\\+\\d+")
#"180101:0050+10870"
```

Comment: Thank you @Tho Vu, this works, too. Though, I am not sure whether it's too restrictive in the sense that all delimiters need to match the pattern. Hence my idea to lookbehind to the second occasion `+` and then look forward to extract the remaining string.